# Generating various sized lists based on the negative binomial distribution

Tags: r, list

I am looking to create multiple lists based on the sequence of numbers (ie 0 0 1 0 1 0 1...) until there are 10 successful trials with the negative binomial distribution.  I am obviously not understanding the list functions too well as my current code isn't retrieving anything worthwhile:

```
z = as.list(supply(1:10, function(x) rnbinom(inf, 10, 1/x)))
```

The probabilities need to vary as per the sequence 1/n with n=1,2,...,10, with the "experiment" continuing until 10 successes occur, then the results ("1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" would be the first for instance, since Pr=1) need to be listed.

Comment: `lapply(seq(10), function(x){rbinom(10, 1, 1/x)})`? You've got some problematic typos in your code, and are asking `rbinom` for infinity numbers, which will cause problems.

Comment: I want the trials to continue until there are 10 successes, so thats why I put the infinite amount there.  So some sequences will have larger results than others.

Comment: That's not how `rbinom` works; you have to tell it up front how many numbers you want. You could do it with `while` loops and `cumsum`, but that's very ill-advised; probably better to make way too many numbers and then subset.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to understand that what `rnbinom` actually returns is the simulated number of failures, not the sequence of trials. So, to simulate based on a random number of failures, you'll need `rep` failures (0) by the number of failures returned, shuffle in 9 successes (1), and end with a success (for a total of 10).

For example, with `prob=0.5`

```
 c(sample(c(rep(1,10-1),rep(0,times=rnbinom(1,10,0.5)))),1)
```

To apply of a list of inverse probabilities

```
lapply(1:10,function(x) c(sample(c(rep(1,10-1),rep(0,times=rnbinom(1,10,1/x)))),1))
```

---

An alternative would be to simulate a sufficient number of the trials themselves and then truncate to the number of desired successes.

```
x <- rbinom(100,1,0.5)
x[cumsum(x)<=10]
```

A proper implementation would handle the extreme case of having not generated enough successes by simulating additional trials to concatenate.

Comment: OK I understand where I was looking at it the wrong way, thats very helpful - thanks